# Table with a column of toggles and the ability to select or deselect all at once

Tags: usability, tables, toggle, select, deselection

I have a a table with a column represent with a toggle.
I need to let the customer an ability to select or deselect them all at once.
Did someone tackle this use case?

I try some ideas, like toggle with 3 states or a dropdown with 2 radio button and clear option but nothing feel correct.

Thanks for any answer

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should a select all toggle button get activated when all toggles get manually selected?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/136632/should-a-select-all-toggle-button-get-activated-when-all-toggles-get-manually-se)

Answer (score 2):

The most common option is a "toggle all" switch, as shown in the figure below:

[image]

Nonetheless, I'd consider a checkbox with a "select / deselect all". Toggles have some usability issues, especially when they're a lot like in your case. Something like the following image

[image: Insert image description here]

Remember that with multiple selection scenarios, you've an indeterminate state (some options are selected, others aren't).

[image]

In this case, you shouldn't use a toggle switch, because a toggle switch is for binary options (true/false), while checkboxes allow for [**tri-state**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox#Tri-state_checkbox) scenarios.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer.
We must give on every raw the ability for boolean option, our customer can choose by himself what to active and what not.

It's pretty confusing because you can active or deactivate, what happen if I choose with the master toggle "select all" and right after deselect one of the rows, do the master toggle become off because if so I expect when I choose deactivate it will deselect all option, so we need the middle state like "intermediate".

It's tricky at toggle level because  people less familiar with this pattern of 3 states.

Comment: That's exactly why I recommend NOT to use a toggle, but a checkbox. The *Indeterminate* checkbox state exists since Windows appeared , so there's a good chance users will understand it, after all it's just a visual cue (at code level, checkboxes and toggles are the same). With a toggle you'll always face the problem you mention because it doesn't have a tri-state like checkboxes, it's only true or false

Comment: A third state for checkboxes isn’t common for all platforms.  And for web content you will need to make it accessible in a non conventional way. By the way checkboxes and toggles define a state not an action and since “select all” is an action it should have a button. Same for “deselect all”. If it is requested to have an “all selected” state, the checkbox or toggle should follow the state of the list (uncheck it when one in the list gets unchecked and vice versa)

Comment: @jazZRo I don't understand your comment. Third state (or tri-state) is a very common feature and it first came with Windows file archive back in early 90s, not ure what do you mean by "platform". Furthermore, this is an accepted UX pattern for web, if you do a search for "select all" you'll get thousands of images showing checkboxes. I don't understand this either "an action should have a button". There are countless actions without buttons (mobile gestures for starters). But the main part is: this is an accepted pattern. See https://material.io/components/checkboxes#usage for an easy example

Comment: I don’t think a (Google) search is the best way to do research  But you are right that the tri-state concept has been around for a long time and has been assumed a suitable solution since. It is not that common for many people anymore though, it’s usefulness is doubtful and it has it’s flaws (does it toggle everything on or off?). Buttons are indeed not the only way to perform actions. For this “toggle all” it seemed the most likely control.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your search and filter options. If users want to deactivate and activate some profiles, allow them to search for those profiles instead of scrolling a lot in a list view. In the filter option, you can add a status filter where the user can see only active and deactive profiles. If a user wants to active or deactive multiple profiles, allow them to select multiple lists from the row and let them take the action.

[image: Search and filter option]

[image: Active or activate profiles]